# how to import middleware library

Tags: java, oracle, import, middleware

i'm noob

i need this class

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/apirefs.1111/e13403/oracle/ide/controls/SortedListModel.html

looks like it orgnize each items asc

how to download this library? this is too hard to find in comparison to downloading pircbot or jsoup

following code is http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/SortedListModelsortableJList.htm

```
        import java.awt.BorderLayout;

        import javax.swing.JFrame;
        import javax.swing.JList;
        import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

        import javax.swing.*;
        import java.util.*;

        class SortedListModel extends AbstractListModel {
          SortedSet<Object> model;

          public SortedListModel() {
            model = new TreeSet<Object>();
          }

          public int getSize() {
            return model.size();
          }

          public Object getElementAt(int index) {
            return model.toArray()[index];
          }

          public void add(Object element) {
            if (model.add(element)) {
              fireContentsChanged(this, 0, getSize());
          }
        }
          public void addAll(Object elements[]) {
            Collection<Object> c = Arrays.asList(elements);
            model.addAll(c);
            fireContentsChanged(this, 0, getSize());
          }

          public void clear() {
            model.clear();
            fireContentsChanged(this, 0, getSize());
          }

          public boolean contains(Object element) {
            return model.contains(element);
          }

          public Object firstElement() {
            return model.first();
          }

          public Iterator iterator() {
            return model.iterator();
          }

          public Object lastElement() {
            return model.last();
          }

          public boolean removeElement(Object element) {
            boolean removed = model.remove(element);
            if (removed) {
              fireContentsChanged(this, 0, getSize());
            }
            return removed;
          }
        }


        public class JListLocationToIndexSample {
          public static void main(String args[]) {
            SortedListModel model = new SortedListModel();

            model.add("A");
            model.add("C");
            model.add("Z");
            model.add("B");

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Selecting JList");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            JList jlist = new JList(model);
            JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(jlist);
            frame.add(scrollPane1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            frame.setSize(350, 200);
            frame.setVisible(true);
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can download the extensions in Jdeveloper from Help -> Check for updates.

Filter only Oracle Extension, then select Oracle Extension SDK. After installation you can create extension projects.